# Apache2 + fcgid download script when query string ends with ".php"

Tags: php, apache2, debian, mod-fcgid

I'm migrating a apache2+php server to mod_fcgid, and when I try to access a link that ends with ".php", the server print out the php source.

```
GET: http://host/?inc=test.php
Does download of the index.php script
```

But when I fix the index.php works.

```
GET: http://host/index.php?inc=test.php
Show the correct page content
```

In my site config:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Limit
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FcgidWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/fcgi-starter .php
```

Where fcgi-starter is a custom sh to wrap /etc/php5/cgi

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/etc/php5/cgi/
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php
```

How to change the config to ignore the query string?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is better for ServerFault. But i think

```
?inc=test.php
```

is no really good solution. I hope you have prevent the remote inclusion to hack your site and read files from your server.

when you now, that your include file is everytime a php file then remove **.php** from your url and add them in your script.

But its better when you define it in your script then you don't have any problems.

```
$incFile = false;

switch($_GET['inc']):
    case 'test':
        $incFile = 'test.php';
    break;
default:
    $incFile = 'nofile.php';
```

Comment: I know the vulnerabilities (and the app has some validation, not include directly). I'm not developing, just testing a new server. Sometimes the parameter is ".php". I did not want to have to change the source because has many files and the source is complicated (so bad).

Comment: I've flagged the question to migration to serverfault. Thanks.